# Automatically generating author name using JabRef

Tags: citing, jabref

I am using JabRef to reference papers, but i want to access author name stored corresponding to that entry.

Suppose i have the following JabRef entries

I cite it directory in texstudio using `\cite{bibtexKey}` which will produce ouput something like `[7]`

But i also want to access to also access author/editor name corresponding to that entry.

Something like following

`Garbled circuit by \cite{bibtexKey}.author \cite{bibtexKey}`

which automatically genertes

`Garbled circuit by Thomsan et.al [7]`

Comment: What about the `\citeauthor` command from `natbib` package?

Comment: @Troy I am using Jabref , can i use natbib with JabRef

Comment: I have no prior experience with JabRef, but I believe JabRef merely manages the BibTeX database (i.e. the .bib file), whereas `natbib` controls the citations and references within the `.tex` file. I don't see a reason why you can't use them both at the same time..

Comment: JabRef is only for managing bib files. In your Latex document you can use things like `\citeauthor`  or \citetitle from the biblatex package

Comment: @ChristophS @Troy I just added `\usepackage{natbib}` following errors started to appear `Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers` `The `cite' package should not be used(natbib) with natbib. Use option `sort' instead.`

Comment: @ChristophS @Troy i was writing `\usepackage{natbib}` instead of `\usepackage[square, number]{natbib}`, now the errors are removed.  After writing `\cite{bibtexKey}` it gives output suppose `[2]` but after writing `\citet{bibtexkey}` it gives output `(author?) [2]`. How can i resolve it

Comment: @Troy  The authors can only be listed if the .bst file supports author–year citations. The standard .bst files, such as plain.bst are numerical only and transfer no author–year information to LATEX. In this case, \citet prints
“(author?) [21].”  found this information in following link [http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf ]How can i resolve it

Comment: Have you read the documentation (the link in your comment)? I'm not entirely sure I get your problem, but try the `plainnat` bibliography style instead of `plain`. Otherwise, please take some time to construct a minimal working example [(MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to illustrate your problem. You can edit your question by clicking the `edit` button on the bottom left corner of the question.

Comment: @Troy i am using `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` but still not working

Comment: Add a MWE then. It's hard to help when I can't reproduce your problem. It's also possible I'm misunderstanding your question. So an example would really help clarify things

Comment: @Troy as you suggest to create MWE , i was copying data to another folder, as i run code it runs fine. Then i started copying one by all `\input` files and run code just run fine. I was wondered both files contain exactly same data then why are the outputs different. Then i realise there are some auto generated files in my folder that such as filename.tex.B12256, filename.tex.i10892 etc when i deleted those files my code produce output fine. Thank you so much for your guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Note:** Even though the problem turned out to be erroneous files in OP's folder, I believe that the original question still has some merit, and so I'll give a 'textbook' answer.]

**Answer:**

The `\cite{bibtexkey}.author`-like command that you are searching for can be achieved by using the `\citet{<key>}` from the `natbib` package. Or if you just want the name, like Thomson et al., then use the `\citeauthor{<key>}` command from the `natbib` package.

All these are well documented in the [`natbib` package documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib?lang=en).

**Few things to note:** (motivated from comments)

- `cite` should not be used with `natbib`
- Use a bibliography style which actually supports author-year citations, like `plainnat` from the `natbib` package.
- This is a good example where the very act of constructing an MWE by the OP's effort can solve the question. MWE is important! `:D`

Comment: I would recommended using biblatex instead of natbib, it also supports the citeauthor and citetitle command and offers greater support for different styles, author year style is for example the biblatex-apa package